# Elasticsearch connector returns too many results

Tags: search

We are using the Elasticsearch connector and we noticed some inconsistent results in the search, specifically on acronyms or short words like sts, .net, crm. I set the fuzziness value to 0, and this helped with the results. However, now partial word searches are not working. I played around with the fuzziness value, and even setting to a 1 reverts it back to the old result set of getting too many results for the short words, but partial search then works.

Any help is appreciated.